# Why is the concurrence of a mixed state defined as $\max(0,\lambda_1-\lambda_2-\lambda_3-\lambda_4)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, density-operator

Why is the the [concurrence of a mixed state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrence_(quantum_computing)) defined as $\mathrm{max}(0, \lambda_1- \lambda_2-\lambda_3-\lambda_4)$?

I don't understand its concept. Apparently, it defines the measurement of entanglement. According to [Wootter's paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.80.2245) it has something to do with the quantum entropy. I also don't quite get the concept of entropy in quantum physics.

Comment: Hi Kim, welcome to Physics SE! Make sure to include a link to the specific paper (along with the specific section number(s), etc. if relevant) when you refer to the content of a paper. For example, Wootter has written a great deal on this subject so it is hard for anyone to guess as to which paper you have in mind.

Comment: @Dvij D.C, thanks. The link is added.

Comment: are you asking about the entropy in quantum states, or about the concurrence? These are different questions. I'd suggest editing the post to focus it on a single one.

Comment: @glS, Thanks for reminding me that. But I think they have the same meaning. That's why I wouldn't separate them.

Comment: they don't. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_entropy and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrence_(quantum_computing)